# What are some of the best method to reduce data consumption via compressing a JSON?

Tags: json, compression, gzip, data-transfer

So, Basically my app sends data in JSON to the server. The size of data is increasing day by day so is my data consumption (internet data). So, I just wanted to reduce my data consumption. One of the basic way is to gzip the data which i am sending.Some of the thing which I came up while searching is

1. Minify

2.[JSONH](https://github.com/WebReflection/JSONH) - JSON Homogeneous Collections Compressor

Can some one suggest some best method currently used in industry for similar type of thing and how it is implemented.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more intelligent way to send reduce data in JSON to server. Reduce the string length of variables and communicate the same to consuming counter parties. If this is ok to do you can go for it.

For Example:-
    {
      "Server":"Test123"
    }

to
    {
      "s":"Test123"
    }

Comment: There are packages to that and that doesn't reduces much consumption.